# SQL Join with Master/Detail and Sum

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got 2 tables that I need to join and need some help.

**ProjectList**

```
Recnum  ProjectName  Contact
1       Test 1       Me
2       Test 2       Myself
3       Test 3       I
```

**TimeTrack**

```
Recnum  Regular  Overtime
1             8         0
3             4         2
3             8         0
```

**Results**

```
Recnum  ProjectName  Contact  TotalRegular  TotalOvertime
1       Test 1       My                  8              0
2       Test 2       Myself              0              0
3       Test 3       I                  12              2
```

We've got it to the point of fetching all fields, but not all records from ProjectList. Need some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a direct `Inner Join` with Aggregate `Sum` should work

```
SELECT A.Recnum,
       ProjectName,
       Contact,
       Ifnull(Sum(Regular), 0),
       Ifnull(Sum(Overtime), 0)
FROM   ProjectList A
       LEFT JOIN TimeTrack b
              ON a.Recnum = b.Recnum
GROUP  BY A.Recnum,
          ProjectName,
          Contact
```

Comment: That looks like the right direction. But what if I want to add the summed fields to Table1 (B)? And just have those fields = 0 or null if there are no corresponding records in Table2?

Comment: @user2021539 Use `Left Outer Join` instead of Inner Join

Comment: oops! Actually, it didn't ... I want to fetch all records from Table1, not just the records that have matching entries in Table2. Right now it is only showing matches. And I had to change SELECT A.Recnum to B.*

Comment: @user2021539 - check now

Comment: Yeah, that only returns the records from Table2. I need all fields and all records from Table1. If there is a match in Table 2 on Recnum, then it should add the sum to the Total_Regular and Total_Overtime fields.

Comment: ahhh ... I missed that you changed it to a RIGHT. I'm trying to test it now. Can't test it. This is a SQLite3 database. I guess RIGHT OUTER JOIN's aren't supported. At least not in the 2 SQL editors I have.

Comment: @user2021539 - Reverse the table positions with `left join` check now

Comment: @user2021539 - it will be better if you add some more sample data and expected output. which will solve all these confusions

Comment: @user2021539 - Dude add the data in question.

Comment: @user2021539 - Didn't expect that you will add the data in comments

Comment: There! That works. I replaced the first SELECT with the named fields to SELECT A.*, ifnull ...etc ... because there are actually about 80 fields in the ProjectList table. But it worked out perfectly! One other quick question. The new summed fields are named "Ifnull(Sum(Regular))" and "Ifnull(Sum(Overtime))". Can I rename those field titles to ttlRegular and ttlOvertime?

Comment: change `Ifnull(Sum(Regular), 0)` to `Ifnull(Sum(Regular), 0) As ttlRegular`